# Odata Stream data in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, odata

I´m trying to fetch data from an OData Stream to a google sheet. With Excel its drop that easy, but with Google Sheets I´m stuck.

I have a URL which is the Adress for the OData and I have the corresponding Username and Pw to access it.

How can I get the OData in Google Sheets?

I tried the =Importdata() command --> no result;

I found online services which transform the stream to CSV and JASON Data, but I cannot use online services for the data, I need a native solution.